# WPF DataGrid - Dynamic Row Details via Code

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I have the need to show RowDetails in the WPF DataGrid when the user performs an action outside of the grid. The thing is though, I need to be able to switch out exactly what the RowDetails will be based on that. For example, if the click Add, I want to show RowDetails below Row  of type AddRowDetailControl, and if they choose Edit, I would want to show a different control under the same row instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create the datatemplate of your RowDetails dynamically based on what your requirement is.  Inside the datatemplate you can put the controls you need.

Have a look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

Comment: You don't have to create the templates dynamically, you can prepare two templates in your resource dictionary, and dynamically (perhaps using a template selector) switch between them.

Comment: @Aviad - That is an even better solution! :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use the template selector along with the method to set the visibility of the row details. SetDetailsVisibilityForItem